# how to send archive provider message to archive queue with provider name in MQRFH2.usr

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

there is one IIB scenario

Create on Message flow which takes message from MQ inputnode
and transform the message to Provider format and using Mapping Node.

send that Provider message to 3 individual Providers
and archive Provider message to archive Queue with Providers name in MQRFH2.usr.

upto
the Provider message to 3 individual Providers i am good
but
Provider message to archive Queue with Providers name in MQRFH2.usr.
i was not able to resolve can you please mention procedure with esql code ?

[msg_flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONWaK.png)

Comment: This is documented in [Accessing the MQRFH2 header](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=headers-accessing-mqrfh2-header). Have you tried this?

Comment: scenario is like .. from our mobile phone we sending one text msg to three people and keeping backup as what msg we send with three people name .. like that